# How to SELECT the MAX(value) in a GROUP BY statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot, aggregate-functions

### Background

I am pivoting this data using the `CASE` expression for years 2010, 2011, and 2012 and grouping by company. The "measure" that is being pivoted/returned is the `max(state)` for each case/year and it's working great.

### Problem

I am trying to get the most recent record `max(invoice_date)` from all records for each `company_name`, but the query is only returning the `date` where the `CASE` expression is satisfied instead of the `max(invoice_date)`.

### Here is an example of the table data:

```
company_name  |  invoice_date | year      |  state
--------------------------------------------------------
CompanyA      |  20130101     | 2012      |   1
CompanyA      |  20130101     | 2012      |   3
CompanyB      |  20130102     | 2012      |   2
CompanyA      |  20120103     | 2011      |   3
CompanyB      |  20120104     | 2011      |   1
CompanyB      |  20120104     | 2011      |   3
CompanyA      |  20110101     | 2010      |   4
CompanyB      |  20110105     | 2010      |   2
```

### And here is an example of the desired view:

```
company_name  |  invoice_date |  2010   |   2011   |  2012
--------------------------------------------------------------
CompanyA      |  20130101     |   4     |    3     |   3 
CompanyB      |  20130102     |   2     |    3     |   2
```

### And here is an example of the result that I get:

```
company_name  |  invoice_date |  2010   |   2011   |  2012
--------------------------------------------------------------
CompanyA      |  20110101     |   4     |    3     |   3 
CompanyB      |  20110105     |   2     |    3     |   2
```

Please note the `date` is in 2011 for both CompanyA and CompanyB which is not the most recent date in the table for those two companies. I am trying to get the `max(invoice_date)`.

### Solved:

```
select
company_name AS company_name,
max(invoice_date) AS invoice_date,
max((case when (year = 2010) then state else 0 end)) AS `2010`,
max((case when (year = 2011) then state else 0 end)) AS `2011`,
max((case when (year = 2012) then state else 0 end)) AS `2012`,
from tbl
group by company_name 
order by invoice_date desc
```

Comment: I wanted to return the maximum (i.e. most recent) invoice date for each year and company_name and group by company_name and sort by invoice_date... I've actually just figured it out though... I just wrote max(invoice_date) and got the desired result...

Comment: As comments are not guaanteed to be preserved, it is desirable that you post a response to your question and mark it as the answer. This may help future readers who search for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use a prepared statement like this so that it dynamically gets all of the years. That way when 2013 data shows up you don't have to change your query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'MAX((CASE WHEN (year = \'',
    year,
    '\') THEN state ELSE 0 END)) AS \''
    year,
    '\''
  )
) INTO @sql
FROM tbl;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
  company_name AS company_name,
  MAX(invoice_date) AS invoice_date,', @sql, '
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY company_name 
  ORDER BY invoice_date desc');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your query like this:

```
select company_name AS company_name,
  max(invoice_date) AS invoice_date,
  sum(year = 2010) AS `2010`,
  sum(year = 2011) AS `2011`,
  sum(year = 2012) AS `2012`
from tbl
group by company_name 
order by invoice_date desc
```

Especially the funny case statements could be made a lot shorter.